# button.onActionProperty().addListener is not working in javafx

Tags: java, events, javafx

I am new in Java and I am trying Java events but I am absolutely lost. I know events from C# where is no problem with it and they works perfectly, but Java is different universe . I tried to find something on internet but I can't figured it out long time so I am here.

I have one object and I need trigger some action. When this action is triggered I need to call not only one event handler, but more of them from different objects.

For example I just use `Button` class.

There are two ways how to do that:

One way is to use `button.setOnAction` method. But this is not working because when I call this method second time (from another object) I just replace one event handler by another. You can see what I mean in code in method `initEventsUselessWay()`.

Second way is to use `button.onActionProperty().addListener`. But this is not working at all. You can see in method `initEventsNeededWay()`.

So, why `button.onActionProperty().addListener`is not working?

And is there any way how to do this in Javafx?

Finally I will not use Button class, but something like MyClass and I need to implement this here. But if this is not working on Button class it will not work on MyClas neither.

Thank you very much for advice.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaEventsTest1589 extends Application {
private Button btnDemo1;
private Button btnDemo2;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // panel
    Pane rootPane = new Pane();

    // scene
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("events demo");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    // button 1
    btnDemo1 = new Button();
    rootPane.getChildren().add(btnDemo1);
    btnDemo1.setText("Execute Demo 1");
    btnDemo1.setLayoutX(50);
    btnDemo1.setLayoutY(10);

    // button 2
    btnDemo2 = new Button();
    rootPane.getChildren().add(btnDemo2);
    btnDemo2.setText("Execute Demo 2");
    btnDemo2.setLayoutX(50);
    btnDemo2.setLayoutY(50);

    initEventsUselessWay();

    initEventsNeededWay();

    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void initEventsUselessWay() {

    btnDemo1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            runDemoPrimaryReaction();
        }
    });

    btnDemo1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            runDemoSecondaryReaction();
        }
    });
}

private void initEventsNeededWay() {

    btnDemo2.onActionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends EventHandler<ActionEvent>> observableValue, EventHandler<ActionEvent> actionEventEventHandler, EventHandler<ActionEvent> actionEventEventHandler2) {
            runDemoThisINeed_No1();
        }
    });

    btnDemo2.onActionProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends EventHandler<ActionEvent>> observableValue, EventHandler<ActionEvent> actionEventEventHandler, EventHandler<ActionEvent> actionEventEventHandler2) {
            runDemoThisINeed_No2();
        }
    });

}

private void runDemoPrimaryReaction() {
    System.out.println("useless way - primary reaction");
}

private void runDemoSecondaryReaction() {
    System.out.println("useless way - secondary reaction");
}

private void runDemoThisINeed_No1() {
    System.out.println("not working way - No1");
}

private void runDemoThisINeed_No2() {
    System.out.println("not working way - No2");
}

}
```

Comment: `setOnAction` seems working for your code. _this is not working because when I call this method second time (from another object) I just replace one event handler by another_ What do you really mean by this? Show an example.

Comment: When I run this example I expect that both event handlers are called. Method runDemoPrimaryReaction() and runDemoSecondaryReaction().

But they are not. Only one of them is called.

So I exprect that when I click on button "Execute Demo 1" in console I will see in console two rows:

'useless way - primary reaction
useless way - secondary reaction'

or for second demo:

'not working way - No1
not working way - No2'

Comment: `setOnAction` sets an event handler on button action and if you set it for second time, the first event handler will no longer be available. In your case, the event handler will run `runDemoSecondaryReaction` method each time because that's what the button is set to do.

Comment: look at my answer, it would print what you need

Comment: AKS this is not what I need. The example what i provided is maybe too simple. The methods runDemoSecondaryReaction and runDemoPrimaryReaction will be on two different objects (classes) so there is no way how to call them from one method. I will read the articles what Benjamin add on his comment and i will see if answer is there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use addEventHandler:

```
btnDemo1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        runDemoPrimaryReaction();
    }
});

btnDemo1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        runDemoSecondaryReaction();
    }
});
```

I recommend using Java 8, in which case you can write

```
btnDemo1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> runDemoPrimaryReaction());
btnDemo1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> runDemoSecondaryReaction());
```

The `setOnAction(...)` method is a "convenience" method. The way it works is that the `Button` maintains an `ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>.` If you set the value of this property (to an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`), that event handler will automatically be added to the event handlers for the button. If you set it a second time, since it's just a property, it will replace the existing event handler. So you can use this for a slightly quicker approach in the case you only have one handler. (It also plays nicely with FXML.)

`onActionProperty().addListener(...)` is a different thing entirely: it listens for changes in the property itself. So if you register a listener in this way, then call `setOnAction(...)`, the listener you registered with the property will be invoked when you call `setOnAction` (not when the button is pressed).

Have a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117), particularly the first section "Processing events" and the second "Working with convenience methods". The second section makes it clear when setOnAction is actually doing.

Comment: thank you all guys now I know what way I have to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think of an 'action' as a property of the `Button` rather than an event.
A `Button` can only have one action at a time, hence you are setting it to one value and then changing it to another which means only the code in the second handler will execute.

The action property is implemented using one of the JavaFX property classes which provides built in property change notification. When you call `button.onActionProperty().addListener(...` you are adding a listener that will be invoked *when the action is changed.*

Try calling the `addListener(...` code before calling `setOnAction(...` and it should be clear what is happening.

If you want to think of this in terms of C# then

- `button.setOnAction(..` is like a property e.g. `button.Action = ...`
- `button.onActionProperty().addListener(...` is like an event e.g. `button.ActionChanged += ...`

If you are new to JavaFX and need some help with their particular implementation of properties and events I can suggest the following resources:

- [Creating JavaFX Properties](http://blog.netopyr.com/2011/05/19/creating-javafx-properties/)
- [Creating read-only properties in JavaFX](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/02/02/creating-read-only-properties-in-javafx/)
- [JavaFX: Handling events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117)
- [JavaFX: Using properties and binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107)

**Update:**

After reading your comments I realise this isn't really JavaFX specific but about events in general. Events are just an implementation of the observer pattern ([even in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)).

A basic implementation might look something like this although there is little point in writing this yourself as JavaFX does include a built in way registering listeners for events as demonstrated by James_D.

```
public interface MyListener {
    invoke();
}

class MyButton extends Button {

    List<MyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MyListener>();

    public void addListener(MyListener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }

    private void invoke() {
        for (HelloListener l : listeners)
            l.invoke();
    }

    this.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            this.invoke();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand now what is happening. Thank you Benjamin. But now what I have to do to resolve what I need? Hwo to implement property or method what provide registration for many object to listen one event? for example one button click? I need to implement something like:<br/>
myObject.addListener(OneMethodFromOneObject)<br/>
myObject.addListener(SecondMethodFromSecondObject)<br/>
myObject.addListener(AnotherMethodFromAnotherObject)<br/>

Comment: Yes Benjamin, that probably what I need to implement - MyListener interface. I will try and will inform how I did it. Thanks a lot! I am just supprised that there is only this manually way to do this in Java.

Comment: My example is for information only to show how this might be implemented (in a very simple way). James_D's answer shows the canonical JavaFX way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment

> So I exprect that when I click on button "Execute Demo 1" in console I will see in console two rows: 'useless way - primary reaction useless way - secondary reaction'

you need to call both the methods in the same event handler as following:

```
btnDemo1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        runDemoPrimaryReaction();
        runDemoSecondaryReaction();
    }
});
```